# SOA Composite NOT Reading from JMS Queue

Tags: jms, soa

I am trying to read message from JMS Queue to SOA Composite. I have built very basic example and configured JMS Adapter. JMS Queue is reading message through JAVA client. However, no message is hitting SOA Composite I deployed i.e No instances are running in Enterprise Manager.. Any guess what I am missing here ?

Thanks,
Pervaiz Khan.

Answer (score 0):

I would test to make sure your JMS adapter can send/receive messages. Create a simple composite to post a JMS message, and another one to read the same queue.
If SOA Suite  JMS adapter is working and you can send/receive messages - then the problem lies elsewhere.

I don't know what this means:

> JMS Queue is reading message through JAVA client.

Do you mean to say your Java program is **posting** the message to the queue? Are you sure? have you looked into the WLS console to verify the message is there?

Also, please post version and platform when asking these types of questions, so we can better help you.